# passing a reference to virtual class implementation as thread argument

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, virtual-inheritance, stdthread

Once again I need your help making `std::thread` work with templated objects. This time my issue is in one of the arguments.

I try passing a reference to a (valid) instantiation of a virtual class as one of the arguments of my thread, and it just doesn't work. Note that passing a pointer instead of a reference solves everything. But still, why can't I give a reference (which I prefer, for many reasons)

Small code reproducing my error :

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class functor { public: virtual T operator()(T) const = 0; };

template<typename T>
class square : public functor<T>
{
    public:
        T operator()(T f) const { return f*f; }
};

template<typename T>
void thread(const functor<T>& func, size_t imin, size_t imax) // line1
{
    for(size_t i=imin; i<imax; ++i)
    {
        T arg = T(i);
        std::cout << arg << "=>" << (func)(arg)) << std::endl; // line2
    }
}

template<typename T>
void threadlauncher(const functor<T>& func, size_t imin, size_t imax, size_t nbthread)
{
    size_t window = (imax-imin)/nbthread + ((imax-imin)%nbthread?1:0);
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (size_t idthread=0; idthread<nbthread; ++idthread)
    {
        size_t tmin = std::min(window*(idthread+0), imax);
        size_t tmax = std::min(window*(idthread+1), imax);
        threads.push_back(
            std::thread(&thread<T>, func, tmin, tmax) // line3
        );
    }
    for (std::thread& thread : threads)
        thread.join();
}
int main()
{
    square<float> func;
    threadlauncher<float>(func, 0, 10, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler (gcc 4.9.2) tells me that my object is invalid because `operator()` is virtual in `threadlauncher`

Note that changing code to pass thread's argument using pointers solves this

```
void thread(const functor<T>* func, size_t imin, size_t imax) // line1
std::cout << arg << "=>" << (*func)(arg)) << std::endl; // line2
std::thread(&thread<T>, &func, tmin, tmax) // line3
```

How can I make him understand that my reference is valid ?

### Edit

I get an long/unreadeble error message from the compiler. I guess the important part is

```
src/functorthreads.cc:50:38:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/functional:1713:9: erreur: invalid abstract parameter type ‘functor<float>’
         __type;
         ^
src/functorthreads.cc:6:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘functor<float>’:
 class functor
       ^
src/functorthreads.cc:9:13: note:   T functor<T>::operator()(T) const [with T = float]
   virtual T operator()(T) const = 0;
```

Comment: What is the _exact_ error the compiler gives you? Chances are you're trying to instantiate a copy of `functor<T>` when you create the thread.

Comment: I edit my post with what I believe are relevant parts of the (very long) compiler error

Comment: Use `std::cref`. The thread argument's getting copied internally, which slices it and causes the pure virtual error. This is exactly the same problem as if you'd tried to use `std::vector<functor<T> const&>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::thread` takes *copies* of it's arguments.  It doesn't matter that the argument to the function is a reference....the `thread` constructor will still copy the arguments since they are being passed to another thread.  That's why pointers work, since they are being copied.

If you know that your object will remain in scope throughout the lifetime of the thread, you can use `std::ref` to wrap your argument:

```
std::thread(&thread<T>, std::ref(func), tmin, tmax)
```

Comment: Thx. Aditionnaly to this ref, my real application's thread does have vectors in it's argument. Wrapping everything in `std::cref` solved the issue an improved the performance (no copy needed).

I'm wondering why does `std::thread` makes copy ? Is it to avoid data races ?